# How to fix the undefined error in typescript and react

Tags: typescript

Hi i have the code like below which calls isSomeFunction method which returns true or false. but in here the argument sometimes can be undefined. so i want to call this function only when selectedItems is not undefined how can i do it.

```
<Button
  disabled={
    isSomefunction(assetIds, selectedItems) || //error here 
    isButtonDisabled 
  }/>
```

i get type undefined is not assignable to type string.

how can i check if selectedItems is not undefined and then call the isSomeFunction in above case so that i dont get the error.

could someone help me with this i am new to programming. thanks.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also check for `selectedItems` like this:

```
<Button
  disabled={(selectedItems && isSomefunction(assetIds, selectedItems) 
   || isButtonDisabled)}
/>
```

Comment: i tried that and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Can you provide more context then?